# Laravel how to add relationship between two pivot table?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following relationships:

1- `Organization` *belongsToMany* `Officials`

```
class Organization extends Model {
     public function officials()
     {
         return $this->belongsToMany(Official::class, 'organization_officials', 
             'organization_id', 'official_id');
     }
}
```

2- `Official` *belongsToMany* `Organizations`

3- `Official` *belongsToMany* `Positions`

```
class Official extends Model {
     public function organizations()
     {
         return $this->belongsToMany(Official::class, 'organization_officials', 
             'official_id', 'organization_id');
     }

     public function positions()
     {
         return $this->belongsToMany(Official::class, 'organization_officials', 
             'official_id', 'position_id');
     }
}
```

The result of above relation is in a table `organization_officials` which shows the list of positions an official hold in an organization.
Now another table has the following relationship:
1- `incident` *belongsToMany* `organization_officials`

What I want to get is:

1- `incident->officials`

2- `incident->organizations`

3- `official->incidents`

4- `organization->incidents`

5- `official->organization_officials`

I can not add direct relationship between `incident` and `officials/organization` as `incident_officials` and `incident_organizations`, because I should link incident to the official specific position he/she had in an organization. So when in have list of positions of an official, I want to get incidents occurred during that specific position.
Now how I can define this relationship between `official->position` and `incidents` ?
Thanks for any suggestion and help

Comment: Try a `hasManyThrough` relationship? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: Perhaps a typo in your example code, but your relationships for the `Official` model are not referencing the correct classes, and the positions relationship is referencing the wrong table. It might be more helpful to define a `OrganizationOfficial` model instead of using pivot tables, as there are some caveats when using the many-to-many relationship, or take a look at https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep for some ideas.

Comment: @upful that pivot table `organization_officials` include another column `position_id` as well.